# Homoclinic Orbit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone explain why $ \phi_{-T}(p)=p $ on a homoclinic orbit for $T$ finite time and $p$ a equilibrium point.

I understand that $ \phi_T(x)=p $ for $x$ a point on the orbit but do not understand why when you try to the other way around the orbit it doesn’t simply take you back to $x$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: An equilibrium point does not lie on an homoclinic orbit. A homoclinic orbit connects, in the limit to $\pm\infty$, some equilibrium point with itself. The only solution starting in an equilibrium point is the constant solution (the dynamical system being smooth enough to introduce the flow function). Starting in $x$ on the homoclinic orbit you can only get $\lim_{t\to\pm\infty}\phi_t(x)=p$.

Comment: So if you are at p you are essentially stuck there